# QStyledItemDelegate: differentiate the cause for closeEditor() or setModelData()

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qstyleditemdelegate

I'm using a `QTableWidget` and need some custom handling of the editing, so I set a `QStyledItemDelegate` on it.

When the user finishes editing, the signal `closeEditor()` is emitted, which I connect to to process the entered data. This signal is both emitted when Enter/Return is pressed, and when the user clicks somewhere else (outside the `QTableWidgetItem` to be edited).

My question is: Is is possible to differntiate if the user presses Return/Enter or clicks somewhere else? I'd like to handle the "click outside" just like an ESC press (no data is changed and the original value of the `QTableWidgetItem` is restored). By now, both cases change the data.

`QAbstractItemDelegate::EndEditHint` (which is emitted with `closeEditor()`) does not give me that information.

Thanks for all help!

Edit:

To process data before it's written back to the model, one can implement `setModelData()`, but still, there seems to be no way if this function was called by pressing Enter/Return or by clicking somewhere else …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently made a sample to become (more) familiar with [`QStyledItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QStyledItemDelegate.html) concerning inline editing of cells:

In this sample, I did the update of underlying data model overloading [`QStyledItemDelegate::setModelData()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QStyledItemDelegate.html#setModelData).

After having read this question, I just tested what happens if input is finished (or strictly speaking: aborted) by <kbd>ESC</kbd>. This is what I observed:

1. The underlying data is kept unchanged.
2. Digging deeper (i.e. setting a break-point into my overloaded `setModelData()`), I observed `setModelData()` is even not called in this case.

May be, the OPs issue can be solved easily by a little re-design of his delegate.

Finally, my derived class (declaration) I used to achieve a "full-featured" delegate to edit table cells inline:

```
class ValueNameDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate {

  // methods:
  public:
    /// @name Construction & Destruction
    //@{

    /// constructor.
    ValueNameDelegate();

    /// destructor.
    virtual ~ValueNameDelegate() = default;

    // disabled:
    ValueNameDelegate(const ValueNameDelegate&) = delete;
    ValueNameDelegate& operator=(const ValueNameDelegate&) = delete;

    //@}
  protected:
    /// @name Overloaded Event Handlers
    //@{

    // inserts editor in table (by setParent(pQParent)) and
    // returns the editor widget to edit cell.
    virtual QWidget* createEditor(
      QWidget *pQParent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &qOption,
      const QModelIndex &qMIndex) const override;

    // removes editor from table (by setParent(nullptr)).
    virtual void destroyEditor(
      QWidget *pQEditor, const QModelIndex &qMIndex) const override;

    // reads data from table model and updates editor.
    virtual void setEditorData(
      QWidget *pQEditor, const QModelIndex &qMIndex) const override;

    // reads data from editor and updates table model.
    virtual void setModelData(
      QWidget *pQEditor, QAbstractItemModel *pQModel,
      const QModelIndex &qMIndex) const override;

    //@}
};
```

Note:

In my case, there is only one editor widget created before-hand. It is re-used for every cell editing (instead of creating for each edit a new one).

This is a little bit different from the [Qt Spin Box Delegate Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-spinboxdelegate-example.html) but works as expected.

I cannot imagine how this shouldn't make any difference concerning the OPs problem.

---

According to feed-back, OP wants to handle the focus-lose event like abort of input. This is in opposition how this is handled by default in [`QLineEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html).

So, my solution is to provide an overloaded version of [`QLineEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html). Instead of changing the behavior of [`QLineEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html), it simply tracks in a member `bool _confirmed` whether <kbd>Enter</kbd> was pressed. The most tricky part was to identify another suitable event or signal to reset the member. Finally, I decided that `focusOutEvent()` is just called at the right time and hence suitable for this task.

`testQLineEdit-Finished.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class LineEdit: public QLineEdit {
  private:
    // flag: true ... last finished editing was confirmed
    bool _confirmed;
  public:
    // Construction & Destruction
    explicit LineEdit(
      const QString &contents = QString(), QWidget *pQParent = nullptr):
      QLineEdit(contents, pQParent),
      _confirmed(false)
    {
      QObject::connect(this, &QLineEdit::returnPressed,
        [this](){ onSigReturnPressed(); });
    }
    LineEdit(QWidget *pQParent): LineEdit(QString(), pQParent) { }
    virtual ~LineEdit() = default;
    LineEdit(const LineEdit&) = delete;
    LineEdit& operator=(const LineEdit&) = delete;

  public:
    // returns whether last finished editing was confirmed.
    bool isConfirmed() { return _confirmed; }
  protected:
    virtual void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *pQEvent) override
    {
      _confirmed = false;
      QLineEdit::focusOutEvent(pQEvent);
    }
  private:
    void onSigReturnPressed() { _confirmed = true; }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  LineEdit qEdit(QString::fromUtf8("Hello World"));
  qEdit.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qEdit, &LineEdit::editingFinished,
    [&]() {
      qDebug() << "Edit confirmed:" << qEdit.isConfirmed();
    });
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

[image: Snapshot of testQLineEdit-Finished]

The output of `Edit confirmed: true` was achieved by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the `false` lines by clicking around.

This is done rather simple and might be done more sophisticated. However, it shows the principle achieved with a rather low number of code lines.

Comment: Thanks for your class definition! But how will it distinguish between "Enter pressed" → "setModelData() called" and "Clicked somewhere else" → "setModelData() called"?

Comment: OK. I must admit: "Clicking somewhere else" is what we always want to "confirm" an input. (We did a lot of extra work to achieve this in gtkmm 2 and were very happy that it's for free in Qt.) In this case, you probably have to change the behavior of `QLineEdit`.

Comment: I extended my answer and made a rather simple approach which doesn't change the behavior of `QLineEdit` but tracks whether editing was finished by [Enter].